# MultipleDetailViews WITH UINavigationController and MWFeed

Tags: ios, ipad, parsing, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using Apple's MultipleDetailViews to have a SplitView going to various nibs. One of my nibs goes to a NavigationController based off of this code http://programming4.us/mobile/3678.aspx

But no matter what I do I can't get the navigationbar to show, and when I click on the rows nothing happens.

Another nib goes to MWFeedParser. Like the first nib with the NavigationController, the rows all show up properly, but nothing happens when I click on them.

It builds without failure or warning, and the app doesn't crash at any point. Literally nothing happens when I click on the rows for the parser or navigation controller.

Nibs that are webViews work fine and I can click around in them and can use "back" and forward" buttons, so I'm sure it has to do with tables and passing information. But this is where I am stuck!